# What is the difference between PhDs in the US and Europe (in terms of employment)?

Tags: phd, united-states, europe

It is frequently mentioned that PhD students are employed in Europe (e.g. the Netherlands, Scandinavia, etc). I still don't understand how this affects a PhD program.

What is the difference when one enrols as a PhD student in the US or has a work contract in the Netherlands? Is there any specific difference in responsibilities, expectations, freedom, etc?

Please make a tangible comparison rather than listing various possibilities. If a student enrols in a PhD program in the US or in the Netherlands, how will their work and life be different?

Comment: Having been a grad student in the US, and a post-doc at a Dutch institute with grad students (albeit some time ago), I'm not sure there was much difference in work or life for a student at either place (over and above general differences in work/life in the respective countries). Your mileage may vary...

Comment: Workplace rights are generally afforded to employees but not students.

Comment: Europe is dozens of countries with different legal and academic systems. Asking about the Netherlands might be fine, Europe, not so much. I wouldn't expect the same answer for Portugal, Norway and Belarus at the same time.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi not all the countries you quoted employ PhD students.

Comment: @Googlebot You got my point, kudos.

Comment: What do you mean by _employed_? When I was a PhD student, my official status was a _supernumerary employee_, but I wasn't technically employed, and my _salary=stipends_. So I was an unemployed employee (and that was in Europe). Additionally, as Najib noted, there will be completely different laws, settings and cultures among different European countries (and take into account that some are, and some are not members of the EU), and among unis in the same country. Duh, my uni nearly never employs a PhD student, but a 2nd uni in the same city does it regularly. So, your question is too broad.

Comment: _Is there any specific difference in responsibilities, expectations, freedom, etc?_ These vary between countries, universities, faculties, departments, programs one is enrolled in, supervisors,... So, do you expect a comparison between all of the dozens (or even hundreds?) of thousands PhD students' situations?

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad. I have 2 suggestions on how to make this answerable: Firstly, clarify (if you are) that you're just interested in the differences that relate directly to whether somebody undertaking a PhD has student or staff status (ie whether they're employed or not). This might be differences in employment rights, working conditions and so forth; don't leave it so broad that it's "how is doing a PhD different in these countries", because that's a huge topic.
Secondly, as others have noted, Europe is heterogenous. You need to specify the country that you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Geographically, the UK is between the Netherlands and the US. In many aspects, the system is something in-between. There has been a long debate in the UK for giving the status of full employment to PhD students or not. This is a brief list of pros and cons argued by both sides of the debate.

Note that these are not my opinion, and I am simply narrating what I recall. A quick search in the UK academic websites can provide sufficient resources.

**Pros**

- An employed PhD has better work conditions and rights.
- They have better reception in the society. For instance, when it
  comes to renting a house, PhD students are considered students, and
  most houses are not available to student tenants.

**Cons**

- PhD stipend is tax-free, but upon employment, the salary is taxable.
- The salary is lower than £32,000 (typical for postdocs), and
  international students should pay around £15,000 tuition fee.
- non-EEA students cannot get Tier 4 student visa and should apply for
  a work visa.

In conclusion, there is not much difference in terms of academic experience.